# How to rename list ids according to current position using jquery .sortable()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

First of all I am sorry that I cannot explain the scenario as for my poor english.This is what actually I need to do. 
I have a list as follows,

```
<ul id="sortable" class="sortable">
<li id="1">1</li>
<li id="2">2</li>
<li id="3">3</li>
<li id="4">4</li>
</ul>
```

list IDs and their values are same.Normally,if I move list ID 4 to top using jquery sortable then I get the new list as,

```
<ul id="sortable" class="sortable">
    <li id="4">4</li>
    <li id="1">1</li>
    <li id="2">2</li>
    <li id="3">3</li>    
    </ul>
```

But What I need to do is rename/reorder the IDs to Ascending as for current order of list.
which means

```
ID 4 => ID 1
ID 1 => ID 2
ID 2 => ID 3
ID 3 => ID 4
```

Is this possible using jQuery .sortable(). If so how would I overcome this problem?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: The whole idea of changing `ids` on the fly sounds pretty wrong.

Comment: @MelanciaUK Thanks for your comment.If so Is it possible to change list value as above rather than Ids? Thanks

Comment: You can do it for sure. @blgt just provided an answer. You just need to adapt it.

Comment: Please see the sorting logic which doesn't change id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with any of a number of supported events. For this example I'll use [stop](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-stop):

```
$(".sortable").sortable({
    stop: function(e, ui) {
        $(this).children("li").each(function(idx, elt) {
             $(elt).attr("id", idx);
        });
    }
});
```

**However** note that this (changing id-s) is generally considered bad practice, there should be a way for you to achieve your results without it. Also, if you're concerned with backward compatibility remember that id-s starting with a number are not part of the standard in HTML4.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.This solves my problem.Since it said to be a bad practice to do this,I decided to change the value of the list rather changing list id for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort like this

```js
function sort_by_id(a, b) {
  var sa = a.id, sb = b.id;
  return sb>sa ? -1 : sb<sa ? 1 : 0;
}

function sortList(){
    var list = $("#sortable > li").get();
    list.sort(sort_by_id);
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        list[i].parentNode.appendChild(list[i]);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" onclick="sortList()">Sort list</a>
  <ul id="sortable" class="sortable">
    <li id="4">4</li>
    <li id="1">1</li>
    <li id="2">2</li>
    <li id="3">3</li>    
   </ul>
```